# Using Ninject in .NET RESTful application?

Tags: c#, ninject, ioc-container, ninject-extensions

I'm new to RESTful services and haven't had to freshly wire up a stack using IoC in a while, so this is giving me a mild stroke.

I have a WCF service that looks like this (simplified):

```
public interface IESIID
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{guid}/{id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Message LookupESIID(string guid, string id);
}

public class ESIID : BaseREST<ESI>, IESIID
{
    private readonly ITXESIIDService _bllSvc;

    public ESIID(ITXESIIDService svc)
    {
        _bllSvc = svc;
    }

    public Message LookupESIID(string guid, string id)
    {
        return GetById(guid, id);
    }

    private Message GetById(string guid, string id)
    {
        apiAuthentication = new APIKeyAuthentication();
        if (!apiAuthentication.IsValidAPIKey(guid))
            return APIError();

        //_bllSvc = new TXESIIDService(); <--- WANTING TO AVOID THIS!!!!
        var results = _bllSvc.SelectByID(id);

        return results.Count == 0 ? NoResults() : CreateMessage(results);
    }
 }
```

Fine, that's pretty straight forward.  I did add a constructor parameter because with the call to the BLL TXESIIDService method.

So now, I've altered my Global file for Ninject which now looks something like this:

```
 public class Global : NinjectWcfApplication
{
    protected override void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes();
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return new StandardKernel(new RestServiceModel());
    }

    private static void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("ESIID", new NinjectServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ESIID)));
    }

}
```

and also added my module:

```
 public class RestServiceModel : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ITXESIIDService>().To<TXESIIDService>();
            Bind<IDoNotSolicitService>().To<DoNotSolicitService>();
        }
    }
```

And for troubleshooting I added by own NinjectServiceHostFactory

```
 public class NinjectServiceHostFactory : WebServiceHostFactory 
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        var serviceTypeParameter = new ConstructorArgument("serviceType", serviceType);
        var baseAddressesParameter = new ConstructorArgument("baseAddresses", baseAddresses);
        return KernelContainer.Kernel.Get<NinjectServiceHost>(serviceTypeParameter, baseAddressesParameter);
    }
}
```

When I run this as in I get an error that the line:

```
return KernelContainer.Kernel.Get<NinjectServiceHost>(serviceTypeParameter, baseAddressesParameter);
```

cannot be null.

Obviously I'm missing something here, but I can't figure out what. I've tried various things at this point and most examples I see are for WCF services and the RESTful ones I've manage to find are just a bit too geared for those familiar w/Ninject or IoC regulars.

Also, In my Business and Data layers (using entity framework), I'm looking to implement Ninject there as well, is it best practice to have the layers wired up separately or is it possible to do it all in one spot?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**
I have corrected the binding issue, but this still bombs on me.  I'm using Ninject.Extensions.Wcf and it's bombing looking for NinjectWcfApplication.cs file which doesn't seem right at all.  I used NuGet to include a package for Ninject, could this be a version issue?

Comment: Bitout of context but I wouldn't advice to use WCF REST for your REST API. That project is dead.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a typo, but are you meaning to bind interfaces to themselves in your module? Usually you bind an interface to a concrete type. If Ninject tries to instantiate an interface type, it will definitely fail, and depending on specific error-handling behavior of your Ninject setup it'll either throw out or return null. So, make sure the module is configured to look for a real class:

```
public class RestServiceModel : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ITXESIIDService>().To<TXESIIDService>();
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're totally right, and that was corrected.  The issue I have now is that I'm using the Ninject.Extensions.Wcf and apparently it or I am missing files.  Great.  Anyway, Thanks for the heads up on the Binding issue I'll edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You always have to call the base method when overriding a virtual method. See `Application_Start()`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your update: I am new to ninject so I don't know anything about older versions but I suppose you try out the [Example Ninject Extensions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf/tree/master/src/Examples) first. If they run, you know it must be something else.